# how to delete old image from destination folder when updating image in laravel?

Tags: file-upload, laravel-5

i have done image update function.The following code updates only the file name in the database but i need to remove the old image from the destination folder too while updating else the folder size will become too large. Any Ideas would be great. Here my code.

```
public function updateQuoteItemImage($image){

 $file=Input::file('filename');
 $random_name=str_random(8);
 $destinationPath='images/';
 $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $filename=$random_name.'_quote_itm_image.'.$extension;  
 $byte=File::size($file); //get size of file
 $uploadSuccess=Input::file('filename')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
 $data=QuoteItemImage::findOrFail($image->id);
 $data->quote_item_id=$image->quote_item_id;
 $data->filename=$filename;
 $data->filesize=$byte;
 $data->save();
return Common::getJsonResponse(true, 'image updated', 200);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unlink function to remove the file that you want. Look at the example bellow:

```
unlink(public_path('name-of-folder') . $nameOfImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file::delete before you update the record.

```
<p>if(Input::hasFile('image')) {</p>

    <p> File::delete('filename');</p>
<p> // Delete old image</p>

<p> } </p>
```